# Django set django session cookies programmatically

Tags: django, session, cookies, multi-tenant, saas

I am creating a saas, software as a service site with django.

Due to the project requirements the users are inside schemas/tenants, for that im using the fantastic [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) app, one user can have accounts inside different schemas (they share username and password) ... i want to let the user move throught the different schemas they are in more or less freely ... for that i have created a view where the user can select on what schema he wants to be on.

When i use an application wide cookie session that is when i have the cookie setting as ".domain.ext" ([django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain)) that works fine but its NOT the behaviour we really want for our application.

What we really need is to be able to have different versions of the app on different browser tabs.

So we have to set the cookie configuration to "domain.ext", then everything breaks because the original view is on one tenant and the next view (where the just logged user really belongs) is inside other tenant then the old cookie is deleted.

So the question is how can i programmatically set the cookie correctly on the new view so the user that really belongs to that tenat is still authenticated.

Or is there any alternative approach we could use for that? Any examples?

**EDIT TO CLARIFY as demanded:**

Person A belongs to 2 schemas SH1 and SH2 on both of them he has the same username and password.
On every password change the password hash is replicated on all the schemas they belong to so they dont have to remember specific passwords or usernames.

When the person is logged on SH1 the url will be sh1.domain.com when he is logged on SH2 the url will be sh2.domain.com

So lets say the person is now logged on schema SH1, he decides to switch to schema SH2, to be able to do that i need the user to still been authenticated so that view has to be on the SH1 schema, but then its redirected to the new schema force authenticating the user but since the cookie is set as domain specific (default django behaviour) when the user lands on the next url sh1.domain.com/whatever the previous cookie is deleted and thus he has to log in again to be able to access.

Comment: It's not clear to me what behavior you're looking for. 

Let's say I've got a User A, who belongs to schemas X and Y, and User B who belongs to schemas Y and Z. What URL/domain layout do you want? What behaviour do you expect? What do you want as the trigger for showing the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the ability to have the *behavior* of a cross-domain cookie, but without actually *using* a cross-domain cookie.

The immediate answer that comes to mind is "well, use a cross-domain cookie". This is pretty much the vanilla example of a situation where you'd want to use use a cross-domain cookie. Engineering a complex solution so that you can avoid using the simple solution never ends well :-) Unless there's some other constraint in play that you haven't revealed, I'd start by questioning whether you shouldn't just be doing this the easy way.

However, assuming there *is* a good reason (and, frankly, I'd be interested to know what that is), the problem you're going to face is that browser security is essentially trying to stop you doing exactly what you're proposing. You want to know, from domain SH2, whether something has happened to a cookie set on domain SH1. That's exactly the situation that cookie security policies are designed to prevent.

The only way you're going to be able to work around this is to have a third party that can share knowledge. When user A logs into SH1, you do password authentication as normal - but you also post a flag somewhere that says "User A is now on SH1". When A logs into SH2, you post the corresponding flag. If A goes back to SH1, you check against the central source of truth, discover that they're currently on SH2, and force a login.

You probably could do this by manipulating cookies and session keys, but I suspect an easier way would be to use an [Authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). What you'll be writing is an authentication backend that is very similar to Django's own backend - except that it will be making checks of cross-domain login status against the central source of truth.

How you implement that "source of truth" is up to you - an in memory cache, database table, or any other source of data will do. The key idea is that you're not trying to rewrite cookies so that the same cookie works on every site - you're keeping each site's cookies independent, but using Django's authentication infrastructure to keep the cookies synchronised as a user moves between domains.

Comment: The only reason i have for that is that a single person should be able to have different tabs (on different schemas) opened on the same browser and still been authenticated on all of them and each of the of course with his own user inside that schema

Comment: Many thanks Russell, even when its not the sollution its the answer i need.

Comment: Then I'm thoroughly confused. The cross-domain cookie *does* allow you to have different tabs open, and be logged into all of them. I know, because I'm doing that on my own SaaS product.

Comment: I know its a very marginal case: The users in mi project are inside the schemas, so at this moment if you want to be logged on more than 1 schema you have to log in on each of them, and thats what we would like not to happen. i will do some checking so if the correct cookie is setted on the browser i just launch a new tab otherwise i will build out that source of truth system you sugested.